# Resetting .bashrc on WSL without using the terminal

Tags: windows-subsystem-for-linux

I was messing with the `.bashrc`, and I made a lolcat echo. Now I can't use the terminal, and I don't know how to reset the `.bashrc` file to default.

Comment: Depending on your Windows version, the WSL file system may show up in File Explorer, and you could just fix it. Although be careful to not mess up the line endings

Comment: You could start WSL as the root user, and copy the `/etc/skel/.bashrc` to your user's home directory from there - see this similar question [Can't fix an error inside of WSL because it's causing WSL to crash](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1315428/cant-fix-an-error-inside-of-wsl-because-its-causing-wsl-to-crash)

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu!  I agree with @steeldriver, either `wsl -u root` or `wsl -e bash --norc --noprofile`.  Either one should get you in.

Comment: While the *"How to restore .bashrc file"* won't help you by itself under WSL, combining the techniques from the two Duplicate answers should be sufficient.  I'm assuming at this point that you've recovered, since it's been a few weeks, but if you still have any issues, please let us know.